# how to use mouse scroll event on overflow hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mousewheel

I am new to Javascript.

I am trying to build a website like this [www.hpmagicwords.com.br](https://www.hpmagicwords.com.br/).
On this website they used all sections with `position:absolute;`.

On the third section of this website they used transform translate effect on mouse wheel scroll. I am trying to make the same effect on my page.

Give me some suggestions with it. How to do it? Which framework can help me to do it?

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g6ewf25t/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe check out http://scrollmagic.io/ you can find some fine examples.

You can always try to make a div with full window height and window width with `overflow: hidden;`. Then the child elements with a `position: absolute;` and set their `top: 100%;` or `transform: translateY(100%);` so they are not visible. And then change their value on scroll minus 1 or something to get them animating up.

But scrollmagic could get you going if you're new.

Comment: Ya scroll magic can help Thanks for the suggestions. Its awesome